# How do I trade with another faction in Rome 2?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

I am unable to trade with many faction because of: "unable to build trading connection with other capital". If I open the diplomacy panel all of these trading marks are red and whatever I do I can´t trade with them because of the message above. I am playing as Sparta.

Anybody has an idea how to build the trading connection? I am running out of money because I can´t trade goods.

Answer (score 4):

This is because trades are going via your nations capital and since Sparta is disconnected from any lands except Athens it is the only trade you can do at the beginning of the game, because they are close to you and that trade is via land. Also note that Sparta does not have a port, so trading via water is out of the equation aswell.

If you want to start trading across the water and in foreign lands you need to take Athens (Historical accurate anyway). This will connect your capital with a port which will allow trading via water.

The red marker in your diplomatic tab means that there is no way to connect your capital with the other factions capital.

Comment: If you already have Athens then can you please post a picture of your map?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, you must have a link that goes all the way from your own capital to the other faction's, if (for example) your capital is on an island and you have another area on the mainland next to the other faction it is NOT linked unless both of your areas have ports to connect them. This is why your not able to setup trade as even though you have an area next to the other factions there is no link for it to reach your capital which will probably be down to a lack of ports.

To fix this; your capital should already have a port so your next step is to take an area that also has a port to form a connection between them, from there you can start trading via land to any faction next to you as it will be able to reach your capital, that is assuming their land is also connected to reach their capital too.